# Battle between Pokemon XY and ORAS

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Can you battle someone with ORAS when you have XY ?

Answer (score 1):

You can with most Pokémon, however there are a few execptions.

Groudon  with Precipice Blades

Kyogre  with Origin Pulse

Rayquaza  with Dragon Ascent

Pokemon holding items available only in Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire, like the items for the new Mega Evolutions.

Of course Smeargle applies to this as well.

Comment: With the actual physical game copies, not just the Pokemon?

Comment: @Ninja Yes, the two physical copies of the game can interact (battling, trading, etc). But **the person using OR/AS** cannot use Pokemon that have items, moves, forms, or abilities that did not exist in X/Y **when interacting with a person playing X/Y versions**.

Comment: That is amazing. Could you possibly tell me how to go about doing that? I am having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: @Ninja While playing a 6th gen game you don't see any difference if you interact with someone playing XY or ORAS, you normally see that player in your friend/acquaintances/passersby list. You can trade and battle with him, with the constraints listed above. As a side note, you can't choose the battle soundtrack, iirc.